# Where to place "common" classes in YII Framework structure?

Tags: yii

I need to create a few classes and would like some help on where this would go in the YII Framework. I know if I create a Model, it must go in the "models" directory. And by the same logic I know where "views", "controllers" etc would go. However, where would the following be placed in my web application:

1. A class that contains a variety of "number" functions such as currency conversion, metric conversions etc?
2. A class that interacts with a REST API? (It interacts with the database)

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get started with adding custom classeses on YII you can check below link.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/165/understanding-autoloading-helper-classes-and-helper-functions/

Hope it'll help you to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example here, it is pretty detailed in my opinion:

[The directory structure of the Yii project site](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/#hh3)

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I want to know EXACTLY in my two examples where they must go. I have already read that page.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can use any PHP class in within Yii. You can place it in the models folder (alongside the Yii generated models) and access them directly like so:

```
$myclass = new MyClass;
$myclass->methodname;
```

Alternatively (or if you run into any issues), you have can place it anywhere in your directory structure and include it in the main index.php (in the root) like so:

```
$myclass = dirname(__FILE__).'/myclass.php'; 
require_once($myclass);
```